# Error reading values from a batch file and printing them

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, cmd.exe

I am trying to read from a file and print the values, but it doesn't work, the variable seems to be set with values of the last run.

read.bat:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (data.bat) do (
echo %%a
set server=%%a
echo %server%
)
pause
```

data.bat:

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

output:

```
 1
 4
 2
 4
 3
 4
 4
 4
```

Expected output:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### The variable seems to be set with values of the last run.

This is because of the way `cmd` parses a batch file. By default variables are expanded at parse time **not** at run time. This means variable in loops are evaluated incorrectly unless you enable [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

> [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time, this option is turned on with the `SETLOCAL` command.
>
> When delayed expansion is in effect variables can be referenced using `!variable_name!` (in addition to the normal `%variable_name%`)

Source [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Use the following batch file.

**test.cmd:**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (data.bat) do (
echo %%a
set server=%%a
echo !server!
)
pause
endlocal
```

**Example Output:**

```
F:\test>test
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [setlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) - Set options to control the visibility of environment variables in a batch file.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot instead using a CALL to a subroutine passing the FOR loop values from the data.bat file to that routine as an argument to then ECHO, etc.:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (data.bat) do (
CALL :Routine "%%~a"

)
PAUSE
GOTO EOF

:Routine
echo %~1
set server=%~1
echo %server%
GOTO EOF
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**CALL**](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html)